# user is not prompted to type and exit automatically

Tags: python, input

I am very new to programming.
I am on a virtual environment and run this code

```
input("ready?  press enter key ")
```

and the result is the user should be able to type but it doesn't allow and exit

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What are you meaning by virtual environment? Are you referring to [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)? What is your OS? Where are you running the `section13-1.py` file? Does it only include this section `input("ready?  press enter key ")`? Please post your complete code.

Comment: I am on windows10. section13-1.py is in c:\python_basic\ .      VS code puts '& C:/python_basic/Scripts/Activate.ps1'  in the result and I cannot type anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is your IDE, I can guess that you are using `Visual Studio`. It is always wait for last input and then exit the program. You can use the `exit` function.

```
input("ready? press enter key ")
exit(0) # successful exit
```